# Generate one rows from many rows into an RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rows, rdd

I need to convert an rdd with two rows, inot an rdd with one row. Example:

```
rdd1=a
     b
```

I need:

```
rdd2=(a,b)
```

How can I do this step in pyspark?
The question could be stupid but I'm new in spark.
"UPDATE"
This is to performing cartesian between rdd2 and rdd3, starting from rdd1. Like:

```
rdd3:(k,l)
     (c,g)
     (f,x)
```

I want this output:

```
rddOut:[(a,b),(k,l)]
       [(a,b),(c,g)]
       [(a,b),(f,x)]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

update my anwser:

```
initRDD = sc.parallelize(list('aeiou')).map(lambda x: (x, ord(x))).collect()

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, batchDuration=3)

lines = ssc.socketTextStream('localhost', 9999)
items = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split())
counts = items.countByValue().map(lambda x: ([x] + initRDD))
```

It looks like broadcast rather than cartesian.

Answer (score -1):

Can you explain a little bit more on your need? Having an RDD with a single row is not a good idea as you lose all parallelism.

If you want to collect the data by key, you can convert the RDD into an RDD of pairs (key and value). Then you can do reduceByKey in order to collect everything by the key to a list simply by having the reduce function be a list concatenation.

Comment: The problem is that I have to perform a measure distance comparing two identical rdds (performing a cartesian between the two), but the result it's too large because I'm working with large scale dataset. So the idea was take the first row of rdd1, perform cartesian with all rdd2 (that is identical to rdd1) and then emit an output file. Remove the first row of rdd1, take the new first, perform cartesian with rdd2 and generate second file etc.

Answer (score -1):

If my understanding of your question is correct, using **flatMap** for this will get you the required output.